# Cannot modify NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I can't uninstall or install NuGet packages. I get the error "Found invalid data while decoding." I'm In Visual Studio 2019. How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems like  issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807079/found-invalid-data-while-decoding-error-updating-nuget-packages) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up closing Visual Studio, deleting the bin and obj folders in all my projects in the solution, and opening it.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)